# 12.04 64 bit - Mouse is not working on startup - keyboard works fine

Tags: mouse

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and erased Windows 7. All has been working well, installing things, rebooting it multiple times. But now I got back on it and restarted it and suddenly the mouse doesn't work.

The keyboard works fine, I can type. And I can even click the mouse. I just can't move it around at all on the touchpad, or even with a USB mouse.

I've read a lot of different questions about this, but I haven't found any good answers. I've read that for some people the mouse activates after like a minute, so far mine hasn't been doing that. I also read about this problem being caused by the Video drivers in some way, and that would make sense, because I did download a driver for my video card before this happened.

But if that is the case, what do I do then? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just also had the mouse mostly stop working on 12.04 64-bit (could still click on app icons  to open them, but could not use mouse to drag them, resize, or do anything else with the mouse -- also could not click on "settings" icon -- BTW, not running Unity here -- sudo apt-get install gnome-panel instead).  Tried resetting the wireless mouse connection and tried new batteries. Didn't help. lsusb in terminal window showed "Bus 008 Device 002: ID 046d:c50e Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse Receiver" so looked ok.  What did fix the problem for me was unplugging the wireless mouse USB connector from the computer and plugging it in again.  Plugged it into a different USB port. Don't know if that mattered. Might give that a try.